# XAML in design mode

Tags: maui

I started to learn microsoft MAUI since a week, 
all videos on youtube are really clear, but no one is explain how can i go to design mode in the XAML page.
Is really without any **WYSIWYG** design? In all videos they just type code! 
thanks

Comment: Yes, you type code to write programs.  There is no XAML designer

Comment: Exactly, there is no designer. You have live preview for emulators (see on Visual Studio the screen), and you have hot reload. The design mode was also removed on the lastest version of xamarin.forms

Comment: The designer of WPF, which also uses XAML, is often broken anyway, don't expect Microsoft to fix those faults anytime soon, just learn to live without a designer.

Comment: WHAT ? really? i should create a project with 10 forms, wich 3 forms must have 4TABS on it with 10 textboxes and a lot of controls!!!!
its...unbeleivable to me in the 2021 programming like i was with COBOL

Comment: @samee Welcome to the Xamarin/Maui world a.k.a. years of unrelenting pain..

Comment: Unbelievable isn't it? Such a useful feature missing from the editor, which btw Android Studio has been doing very well for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually if you are able to compile, the you have Live XAML Preview option in debug. Also application automatically re-renders XAML forms if you are running debug for WindowsMachine.